# Record being created in Access without append

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe5

I am currently creating an application but when running the following code:

```
ADOQRanking.Edit;
ADOQRanking['Bye']:=True;
ADOQRanking['TableAssigned']:=True;
ADOQRanking.Post;
```

... a new record with null values is created in `ADOTPoints` (the table that `ADOQRanking` sorts), with `Bye` and `TableAssigned` both set to true, rather than the intended record being edited. It should also be noted that there is no code in the entire procedure that creates a record in `ADOTPoints`.

Comment: Obviously something is going on which isn't apparent from your description of the problem.  You'll likely get better help if you edit your q to include the source code of your unit and the text version of its DFM.

Comment: We don't do custom assistance requests here ("add me on Skype"), because that means that the answer would not be useful to others. If more information is needed, someone should let you know and you can edit your question to add the details. :-) If you can't explain it here well enough for us to understand, it won't be useful to others in the future who have a similar problem. StackOverflow is a collection of knowledge, so posts should be useful to others as well as you personally.

Answer (score 0):

try to use fields by it's names

```
ADOQRanking.FieldByName('Byte').Value := true ;
```

and so on ..